# How to find out if the binding is used for a given mode?

Tags: key-bindings

The only useful command I found was `:help index` then navigate to a mode I  interested in.

But it explains the whole command list. Is there a function or something else which could give me a simple answer `0` or `1` for a given binding? Or the best I can do is to search through the whole section?

Comment: What's wrong with `:map`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commands for *creating* a mapping, happen to also be the same commands for *listing* a mapping. From `:help map-commands`

```
1.1 MAP COMMANDS                    *:map-commands*

There are commands to enter new mappings, remove mappings and list mappings.
See |map-overview| for the various forms of "map" and their relationships with
modes.
```

If you call it with both a left hand side, and a right hand side, for example:

```
nnoremap i iHello<esc>
```

This *creates* a new mapping. Now, if you call it with *just* the left hand side, this will list all mappings that start with that left hand side. For example, if you ran

```
nmap i
```

It will list *every* normal mode mapping that starts with an `i`. Relevant help section, `:h map_l`:

```
:map    {lhs}           |mapmode-nvo|       *:map_l*
:nm[ap] {lhs}           |mapmode-n|     *:nmap_l*
:vm[ap] {lhs}           |mapmode-v|     *:vmap_l*
:xm[ap] {lhs}           |mapmode-x|     *:xmap_l*
:sm[ap] {lhs}           |mapmode-s|     *:smap_l*
:om[ap] {lhs}           |mapmode-o|     *:omap_l*
:map!   {lhs}           |mapmode-ic|        *:map_l!*
:im[ap] {lhs}           |mapmode-i|     *:imap_l*
:lm[ap] {lhs}           |mapmode-l|     *:lmap_l*
:cm[ap] {lhs}           |mapmode-c|     *:cmap_l*
            List the key mappings for the key sequences starting
            with {lhs} in the modes where the map command applies.
            {not in Vi}
```

The other way to list mappings is if you do not provide a left hand *or* a right hand side. For example, if you just type:

```
nmap
```

this will list *every* mapping that applies to normal mode. The relevant help section (Not sure how to get here. Just type `:h cmapc` then scroll down a little):

```
:map                |mapmode-nvo|
:nm[ap]             |mapmode-n|
:vm[ap]             |mapmode-v|
:xm[ap]             |mapmode-x|
:sm[ap]             |mapmode-s|
:om[ap]             |mapmode-o|
:map!               |mapmode-ic|
:im[ap]             |mapmode-i|
:lm[ap]             |mapmode-l|
:cm[ap]             |mapmode-c|
            List all key mappings for the modes where the map
            command applies.  Note that ":map" and ":map!" are
            used most often, because they include the other modes.
```